# Nx monorepo: elsint can not resolve paths with @ specified in tsconfig.base.json (import/no-unresolved

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, monorepo, typescript-eslint

I'm working on an NX monorepo project. I have linting configured. I have:

`.elsintrc.json`

```
  "settings": {
    "import/parsers": {
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [
        ".ts",
        ".tsx"
      ]
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {
        "typescript": {
          "alwaysTryTypes": true,
          "project": [
            "tsconfig.base.json",
            "apps/**/tsconfig.json",
            "libs/**/tsconfig,json"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  ...
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts",
        "*.tsx"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@nrwl/nx/typescript",
        "prettier",
        "plugin:import/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {}
    },
```

and `package.json`

```
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
```

and `tsconfig.base.json`

```
    "paths": {
      ...
      "@vertigo/utility/dto/query": [
        "libs/utility/dto/query/src/index.ts"
      ...
      ],
    },
```

This should be correct in a far as I understand from [the docs](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-import-resolver-typescript).

However, it is still unable to resove paths specified in `tsconfig.base.json`:

```
 5:27  error    Unable to resolve path to module '@vertigo/utility/dto/query'  import/no-unresolved
```

Comment: I think the fix for this needs to include resolvers for eslint-plugin-import. Have you ventured into this since you created this question? Any updates?

Relevant links:
- https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import#resolvers
- https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/resolvers/README.md

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was solved by editing the `jest.confg.ts` files in the libs.

The `transform` property had wrong values. Honestly without digging into it a lot and finding out the real underlying details, I at least managed to get it working by using one of these.

We have some legacy code, the NX project was put together from different pre-existing projects, where code was written in different styles with different settings for linting etc. Since I am no expert on all of the different sub parts, and have no time to dig into all of it, I decided for now it was better to leave the code as much untouched as I could, and just get the tests to run again. So I experimented a bit and these are the options that have made it work.

```
  transform: {
    '^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)': '@nrwl/react/plugins/jest',
    '^.+\\.[tj]sx?$': ['babel-jest', { presets: ['@nrwl/react/babel'] }],
  },
```

OR

```
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.[tj]s$': 'ts-jest',
  },
```

I would love to dig in deeper to really learn about it, but for now I got it working, and some things will have to wait until I have the time I guess.

Hope it might help someone else. (Let me know what you learn!)